# Create trigger in MySQL 5.7.29 to set a timestamp on changed rows

Tags: mysql

Have tried to search the web and this forum to find a solution for this.

We have a system with a database and lots of tables and a non existing documentation.

I want to add a column to each table that automatically sets a timestamp when the row is changed.

My SQL is not so good that I can figure this out. I keep getting syntax errors.

I found a solution here on stackoverflow, that would do this in a new table, I tried that but got hid with a syntax error that the NEW.id did not exist.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

This is what I've ended up with so fare:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER logInsert AFTER INSERT ON test_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO datalog (action, id, timestamp, data1, data2)
      VALUES ('insert', NEW.id, NOW(), NEW.data1, NEW.data2);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: timestamp is reserved word used for data type. If you named column timestamp, you have to use backsticks in the query around the timestamp column name. Other than that your query looks good (if the datalog table exists).

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger works fine in my MySQL 5.7 (with backsticks around timestamp column name):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datalog;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;

CREATE TABLE datalog (
    `action` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    id INT(11) NULL,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL,
    data1 INT(11) NULL,
    data2 INT(11) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    data1 INT(11) NOT NULL,
    data2 INT(11) NOT NULL
);


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER logInsert AFTER INSERT ON test_table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO datalog (action, id, `timestamp`, data1, data2)
      VALUES ('insert', NEW.id, NOW(), NEW.data1, NEW.data2);
END$$

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO test_table (data1, data2) VALUES (2, 3), (3, 4);

SELECT * FROM datalog;
```

=>

```
action  id  timestamp   data1   data2
insert  1   2020-01-31 07:21:09 2   3
insert  2   2020-01-31 07:21:09 3   4
```

As per your trigger code, the test_table should have id, data1 and data2 columns.

Comment: Updated the question with the sample so fare and it is not the Coloumn change I want to log but the row change setting a timestamp in a new coloumn

Comment: @Jonas Sorry, did not understand what you wanted. I've updated my answer.